# LeafletJS: How to hide legend when layer is clicked?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to show/hide a legend when a certain overlay is clicked, but can't seem to get the legend to hide when the overlay is unclicked.

Here's my sample setup:

```
//establish the data
var popDensity = L.geoJson(popDensity, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    style: myCustomstyle
});

//Create the legend control
var popuLegend = L.control();
popuLegend.onAdd = function(map){
    var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
    container.innerHTML = '<h3>Population</h3><ul id="popuLegend"><li>1000+</li><li>500+</li><li>etc..</li></ul>';
    return container;
};
```

My layers control:

```
var baseMaps = {
    "Base map 1": basemapOne,
    "Base map 2": basemapTwo
};

var ethnicGroups = {
    "Pashtun": pashtun,
    "Tajik": tajik,
    "etc..": etc,
    "District Population": popDensity
};

map.fitBounds(pashtun.getBounds());
L.control.layers(baseMaps, ethnicGroups).addTo(map);
```

Here's my event handler:

```
map.on('overlayadd', function(eventLayer){
    if (eventLayer.name === 'District Population'){
        map.addControl(popuLegend);
    } else {
        map.removeControl(popuLegend);
    }
};
```

**This setup successfully adds the legend control when the 'District Population' overlay is checked, but when it is unchecked, the legend does not remove itself. When you check it again, another copy of the legend is added on top of the previous legend. Any tips?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to listen for 'overlayremove' to listen to the District Population being unchecked. Give this a shot, not entirely sure.

```
map.on('overlayadd', function(eventLayer){
    if (eventLayer.name === 'District Population'){
        map.addControl(popuLegend);
    } 
};

map.on('overlayremove', function(eventLayer){
    if (eventLayer.name === 'District Population'){
         map.removeControl(popuLegend);
    } 
};
```

Comment: that worked! I was using this as an example and wondering why they didn't have to listen for 'overlayremove'? http://jsfiddle.net/T8DHb/8/

Comment: Good to hear. With the radio button in that fiddle if one goes on, one is automatically removed, no need to listen for remove.

Comment: Thanks. A related issue: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188353/leaflet-layer-not-staying-on-top-of-all-other-layers