# Layer not staying on top of all other layers

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to keep a specific layer named `popDensity` on top of all the other layers on my map despite what other layers I may click in the layers control. I am using the Leaflet `overlayadd` event to listen for my `popDensity` layer and then using the `bringToFront()` method to ensure that `popDensity` stays at the top of my other layers when they are clicked.

Here's my sample setup:

```
//establish the data
var popDensity = L.geoJson(popDensity, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    style: myCustomstyle
});

//Create the legend control for the popDensity layer
var popuLegend = L.control();
popuLegend.onAdd = function(map){
    var container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
    container.innerHTML = '<h3>Population</h3><ul id="popuLegend"><li>1000+</li><li>500+</li><li>etc..</li></ul>';
    return container;
};
```

My layers control:

```
var baseMaps = {
    "Base map 1": basemapOne,
    "Base map 2": basemapTwo
};

var ethnicGroups = {
    "Pashtun": pashtun,
    "Tajik": tajik,
    "etc..": etc,
    "District Population": popDensity
};

map.fitBounds(pashtun.getBounds());
L.control.layers(baseMaps, ethnicGroups).addTo(map);
```

Here's my event handler:

```
map.on('overlayadd', function(eventLayer){
    if (eventLayer.name === 'District Population'){
        popDensity.bringToFront();
        map.addControl(popuLegend);
    }
});
map.on('overlayremove', function(eventLayer){
    if (eventLayer.name === 'District Population'){
        map.removeControl(popuLegend);
        map.removeLayer(popDensity);
}
});
```

This setup successfully adds the popuLegend legend control when the 'District Population' overlay is checked, but when it is unchecked, and then checked again, I get the following error in console:

`Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.`

At the same time, when I click on the Pashtun and Tajik layer(s) these layers will show on top of the popDensity layer which defeats the purpose of trying to use the `.bringToFront()` method on the `popDensity` layer.

**how can I ensure that my `popDensity` layer is the top layer at all times as long as that layer is checked on?**

Answer (score 2):

You could look at map panes in leaflet beta or use .bringToFront() on every overlayadd event at least as far as keeping the popDensity layer on top.

Comment: can you show an example of using bringToFront() on every overlayadd event? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert or anything, but I see that when you uncheck you completely remove the layer, and never add it back into the map. maybe it can be as simple as adding `map.addLayer(popDensity);`in your `overlayadd` function before using `bringToFront()`. Hope that helps, and if not I hope you get an answer that helps soon!

Comment: Does it give you the same error? yeah just noticed playing with control and noticed that the unchecking should automatically remove and add layers to map-_-. maybe removing the layer is uneccessary then? try removing the `map.removeLayer(popDensity);` ?